# What type of relationship these two tables will have in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

i have four tables in database:

1. users (for storing user details)
2. conversations (for storing conversations id).
3. conversationsmember (for storing conversations member)
4. conversationsreply (for storing conversations reply)

A user will have many conversations and each conversation will have its members and replies.

here are the details:

Users migration:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->string('name', 32);
$table->string('username', 32);
$table->string('email', 320);
$table->string('password', 64);

$table->timestamps();
```

Conversations migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
```

conversationsmembers migration:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('conversation_id');
$table->integer('user_id'); 

$table->timestamps();
```

conversationsreply migrations

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('conversation_id');
$table->integer('user_id'); 

$table->timestamps();
```

Now in User model, i need to define relationship between users table and conversations table. As they are not directly connected, i used hasManyThrough relation.

..app/models/User.php

```
...
    public function conversations()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('Conversation', 'ConversationsMember', 'conversation_id', 'id');
        }
...
```

When i 'm trying to use it, it's showing a blank array.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a belongsToMany relationship, where conversationsmembers is your pivot table.

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Conversation', 'conversationsmembers');
}
```

You may also want to define the inverse of the relationship in your Conversation model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'conversationsmembers');
}
```

I'm a bit confuse about your migration so I'm not sure that's what you want.